# Chatroom Owner Flag Viewing

Tags: feature-request, chat

It's kind of annoying to not be able to see what is flagged as a room owner. Could we owners under 10k reputation be allowed to see flags coming from said specific room? (And then at 10k normal permissions override)

Comment: I don't think it's necessary as anyone over 10k can see flags in chat all rooms

Comment: Room owners aren't always 10k+

Comment: Of course, but there are enough 10k+ users in the chats that flags will be handled quickly and appropriately. IMO if you really want to see chats that much then rep up to 10k

Comment: But doesn't it make sense that a room owner would have the same powers (such as invalidating flags)? Of course "get 10k rep" is easy to say, but at the quality of Main questions coming in I'm lucky to gain 10 rep for every 8 questions I close. However, it's not a big deal and since I am getting close it may not matter. I just think this would be a good idea as some people don't place value on rep, but are good room owners and still brilliant and trusted that they shouldn't be punished for not wanting to answer every syntax error in the west.

Comment: @bmargulies I am going to rollback your edit because that title makes it sound like I desperately want this to happen when it's just a suggestion :P

Comment: So long as the spelling ends up correct.

Comment: @bmargulies say what now?

Comment: I clicked edit due to a spelling error, and then I was 'inspired'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary.

There are multiple 10k+ users active in the chat rooms and they can see the flags across all of the rooms so they are usually handled with speed and accuracy.

I also do not think it'd be appropriate for room owners to approve/deny flags because there is no rep limit (besides being able to chat) to become a room owner. A user with 20 rep could become an owner in some room and approve flags without properly knowing SO or the chat room's rules.

A *lowered* rep limit for room owners may be more of a possibility, but even then where is that line? In my own case I wouldn't say that I understood proper flagging until 2k~3k, but that isn't the same for everyone. 10k is a way to be assured that they know what they're doing when they approve/deny flags and have contributed to the site extensively.

IMO if you want to see flags that badly you should rep up to 10k.

Comment: Well, not disagreeing, but if somebody makes a room owner out of a n00blet than we have bigger problems in the afformentioned room lol

Comment: I think given recent situations, this stance doesn't seem to make sense anymore. The expectations are higher on chat now, and denying room owners access to a vital portion of chat moderation won't cut it. I'm not saying that vote would be swung a different way, but just that those who were chosen to enforce the rules are given the ability to do so.

Comment: In addition, there are different skill sets for being able to help with development and being a good room owner. I wouldn't ask a security guard for coding help, and I wouldn't ask an engineer to go break up a fight outside. Since rep is predicated on how well you help others with Stack Overflow, using it as a barricade for chat enforcement seems silly.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja I think you fail to address my points in this answer